# java.io.EOFException using ksoap2 lib libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)

Tags: java, android, ksoap2, eofexception

```
03-26 14:12:19.045: E/Webservices(2863): java.io.EOFException
03-26 14:12:19.045: E/Webservices(2863):    at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
03-26 14:12:19.045: E/Webservices(2863):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:560)
03-26 14:12:19.045: E/Webservices(2863):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:813)
03-26 14:12:19.045: E/Webservices(2863):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
03-26 14:12:19.045: E/Webservices(2863):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:486)
03-26 14:12:19.045: E/Webservices(2863):    at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.getResponseCode(ServiceConnectionSE.java:103)
03-26 14:12:19.045: E/Webservices(2863):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:197)
03-26 14:12:19.045: E/Webservices(2863):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
03-26 14:12:19.045: E/Webservices(2863):    at .utils.Webservices.callinternet(Webservices.java:125)
03-26 14:12:19.045: E/Webservices(2863):    at .utils.Webservices.getResponse(Webservices.java:73)
03-26 14:12:19.045: E/Webservices(2863):    at .utils.Webservices.getResponse(Webservices.java:79)
03-26 14:12:19.045: E/Webservices(2863):    at .utils.Webservices.getResponse(Webservices.java:79)
03-26 14:12:19.045: E/Webservices(2863):    at .utils.AsynTask.doInBackground(AsynTask.java:61)
03-26 14:12:19.045: E/Webservices(2863):    at .utils.AsynTask.doInBackground(AsynTask.java:1)
03-26 14:12:19.045: E/Webservices(2863):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-26 14:12:19.045: E/Webservices(2863):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-26 14:12:19.045: E/Webservices(2863):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-26 14:12:19.045: E/Webservices(2863):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-26 14:12:19.045: E/Webservices(2863):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-26 14:12:19.045: E/Webservices(2863):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-26 14:12:19.045: E/Webservices(2863):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

When i call the webservice from android this exception come some time only how can be clear 
this please help me

i atteded

```
ArrayList<HeaderProperty> headerPropertyArrayList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
    headerPropertyArrayList.add(new HeaderProperty("Connection", "close"));
```

this line also but no use

Comment: Did you manage to find out what the problem was?

Comment: @Sebek, No i cant find for the solution

Answer (score 10):

This is a bug, I am getting the same error while using **ksoap2-android-assembly-3.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar**. It looks like this problem has been [prevailing since v3.1.1](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=178) (some users faced this in earlier releases too). A user with gave a workaround to [tackle this problem](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=173&can=1&start=100). According to him,

```
ArrayList<HeaderProperty> headerPropertyArrayList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
headerPropertyArrayList.add(new HeaderProperty("Connection", "close"));
httpSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headerPropertyArrayList);
```

did the trick. I tried it and it worked for me. If you are still facing the problem then you can use **ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar**. I am using this version on another project of mine and it has never given me any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, but I solved it out, actually soap webservice operation(method) name was misspelled that's why java.io.EOFException Exception was thrown by Ksoap2 library So check your operation(method) name, namespace name and soapAction(name space/method name).
I think this will help you to handle this exception

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have faced the same issue.Please use connection time out parameter to avoid this exception.

```
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE("Your Url here",120000);
```

and also set connection close parameter in header.

```
ArrayList<HeaderProperty> headerPropertyArrayList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
headerPropertyArrayList.add(new HeaderProperty("Connection", "close"));
httpSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headerPropertyArrayList);
```

Answer (score -1):

EOFException - Signals that an end of file or end of stream has been reached unexpectedly during input. This exception is mainly used by data input streams to signal end of stream. Note that many other input operations return a special value on end of stream rather than throwing an exception.

So: after `call()` your `HttpTransportSE` instance do `instance.getServiceConnection().openOutputStream().close();`

MyCode:

```
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
try {
    androidHttpTransport.call(mSoapAction, envelope);            
    response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

    androidHttpTransport.getServiceConnection().openOutputStream().close();
} catch (IOException | XmlPullParserException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();           
}
```