# android EOF exception ksoap

Tags: java, android, android-ksoap2

This is code for getting images from the server .when i implement this i am getting error when call another ksoap web service .I am getting an Eof exception.
when i remove the below code the ksoap web service is working.Is anything wrong with the below code?

```
URL url = new URL(s);
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
con.setRequestProperty("connection","close");
InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
imageResources[id] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
is.close();
```

Comment: The code you provided looks good. I encountered a similar problem with EOFException using ksoap2,  it throws some times and some times doesn't. Seems to be a bug in library.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/22680533/813951